# Control columns in Sankey diagram

Tags: r, sankey-diagram, networkd3

I wish to use create a Sankey diagram in `R` with the `sankeyNetwork()` function from `networkD3` where I want to control in what "columns" nodes are located. Consider the following code

```
library(networkD3)

links <- data.frame(source=c("1_a", "1_b", "1_c", "2_b", "2_d"),
                    target=c("2_a", "2_b", "2_c", "3_a", "3_b"),
                    value=c(3,2,5,4,7))

nodes <- data.frame(name=c("1_a", "1_b", "1_c", "2_b", "2_d", "2_a",
                            "2_c", "3_a", "3_b"))
                    
links$IDsource <- match(links$source, nodes$name)-1 
links$IDtarget <- match(links$target, nodes$name)-1

sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes,
              Source = "IDsource", Target = "IDtarget",
              Value = "value", NodeID = "name")
```

This code produces the following plot:

[image: plot1]

However, I wish to align the nodes such that the first column contains "1_a", "1_b", "1_c", the second column "2_a", "2_b", "2_c" and "2_d" and the third "3_a" and "3_b". Adding `sinksRight=FALSE` does not help as it produces the following plot:

[image: plot2]

Is it possible to achieve the desired output?

Comment: You probably want [d3.sankeyJustify](https://github.com/d3/d3-sankey#sankeyJustify), but since networkD3 is using an older version of D3, it is not available through that package.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks